# angular material flex in ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am constructing a dynamic table using angular material row and column layouts. I am using ng-repeat to construct the columns based on pre defined columns in an array of objects called scope.tableLayout. Each object has a flex value. What I would like to do is set the table column width based on the flex value in the object. Is there a way to do this?

My JSfiddle of the table attached where I've tried to set the flex as flex="col.flex" with no luck. Any help is appreciated. 
[My Code in JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/hhmkxq8y/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template">
        <button ng-click="testFn()">Test</button>
        <div layout="row">
            <div flex='col.flex' ng-repeat="col in column"><span>HEADER{{$index}}</span>
                <div layout="column">
                    <div flex style="border: 1px solid black;" ng-repeat="row in [1,2,3]">{{$index}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script> 

    <form-table table-layout=tableLayout|filter:{table_id:1}></form-table>
</div>


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tableLayout =[{"head_id":"GAP Assessment","table_id":"1","table_name":"GAP Table","element_id":"0","element_name":"Action Reference","sort_order":"0","is_multirow":"1","flex":"30","element_sort_order":"4","is_show":"0"},{"head_id":"GAP Assessment","table_id":"1","table_name":"GAP Table","element_id":"1","element_name":"Audit Criteria","sort_order":"0","is_multirow":"1","flex":"30","element_sort_order":"0","is_show":"1"},{"head_id":"GAP Assessment","table_id":"1","table_name":"GAP Table","element_id":"3","element_name":"Document Reference","sort_order":"0","is_multirow":"1","flex":"10","element_sort_order":"3","is_show":"1"}]
});
app.directive('formTable', function() {
    return {
        scope:{tableLayout:'&'},
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){ // normal variables rather than actual $scope, that is the scope data is passed into scope

                    scope.column=scope.tableLayout();
                    scope.testFn=function(){
                        console.log(scope.tableLayout());
                    }



                    //function and scopes go here
                },//return
        transclude:true,
        templateUrl: '/template',
        restrict: 'E'        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted this problem I found my issue - need to use handlebars!

```
flex = "{{col.flex}}"
```

It now works.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/hhmkxq8y/7/)